# How to serve images from subfolders in Javascript via Asset pipeline

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

So I have a folder in my assets/javascripts folder that runs an image slideshow called galleryview. Inside this folder is a themes directory holding images for my "next" and "previous" buttons thus...

assets/javascripts/galleryview/themes/

now the javascript running this, links to these images via this....

```
//Determine path between current page and filmstrip images
//Scan script tags and look for path to GalleryView plugin
        $('script').each(function(i){
            var s = $(this);
            if(s.attr('src') && s.attr('src').match(/jquery\.galleryview/)){
                img_path = s.attr('src').split('jquery.galleryview')[0]+'themes/';
            }
        });
```

HOWEVER, I'm using this in a Rails app now, so I need to point this img_path line to

assets/images/

so what should my imag_path look like now?

```
img_path = ?
```

---

Here is the entire javascript file code on jsfiddle....copy and past this into an editor and 
the area I'm interested in is around line 389.

http://jsfiddle.net/thefonso/Sqmxa/

Comment: Why can't you put all your images in app/images?

Comment: I currently have a copy of the images in app/assets/images. The javascript that runs this jquery plugin is pointing to app/assets/javascript/themes. I need to fix the js code to point to app/assets/images (img_path = ???) I don't know how to do this from within js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this code will exactly work, but I think you can use [the `image_path` helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_path) to get you close. Something like:

```
img_path = <%= image_path 'images/'%>;
```

Put this inside a `.js.erb` file and the ERB shown above should be parsed and output the string `"/assets/images/"`, assigning `img_path` to the value `"/assets/themes/"`

Of course, you could also just do:

```
img_path = "/assets/images/";
```

...but the upside of using the helper, I guess, is in case that the "assets" path ever changes you won't need to update a hard-coded string.

Comment: blessings be upon you my friend, that was it!

Comment: Uh, thanks. I'll take the karma/blessings where I can get them.

Comment: Receive it from any deity you choose (including the spagetti variety) . much thanks.